# Measure how dataset is harmonious or organized

Tags: dataset, pattern-recognition

Suppose we have two set of numbers : A = [1,4,9,16,25,49...100] and B = [1,4,7,7,25,49,64...100]. As you seen the first one is consistently growing, elements of it is square of numbers. But although second one can be described as a square of numbers it doesn't strictly follow any rule and there is no fully suitable way to describe it.

Is there a way or ways to measure how a dataset is "consistent" or has a pattern ?

Answer (score 1):

That's what pattern recognition is all about: you chose a family of possible patterns (another word for this family is "model") and then you fit this model, which means you find the pattern within your family that matches best.

In your case, you want to find patterns in sets of numbers, or rather tuples, since you consider the order relevant. One possible model would be that they are the result of applying a polynomial to integers. You then fit this model and you will see that $A$ belongs to the pattern of squares of integers.